# Execute gethostbyname for maximum 1 second

Tags: php, linux, server, ip, gethostbyname

When I do this:

```
print gethostbyname("google.ro");
```

It prints the IP in less than 1 second.

If  I try to do the same thing with an unexisting domain:

```
print gethostbyname("cduri.ro");
```

It tries to get the IP for like 7-8 seconds and after that it fails and will print the domain instead.

What I want to achieve is to somehow break the `gethostbyname` after 1 second, because I know that it means that the domain does not exist. I have a big list of domains so I can't wait 7-8 seconds for each domain which can't be reached. I want to stop and move to the next one.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I looked in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php
and found this:

Options for the underlying resolver functions can be supplied by using the RES_OPTIONS environmental variable. (at least under Linux, see man resolv.conf) Set timeout and retries to 1 to have a maximum execution time of 1 second for the DNS lookup:

```
putenv('RES_OPTIONS=retrans:1 retry:1 timeout:1 attempts:1');
gethostbyname($something);
```

You haven't seen that? Or you're not using Linux? It's not working for you? There are more suggestions in the manual, I'm not going to list them all.

Comment: Currently I test in my wamp (windows) but when I will go live I will probably have a linux server.

Comment: You did tag your question with Linux, I therefore gave a Linux answer. It is obvious you need a different solutions for Windows. PHP basically uses underlying routines available in the OS, so you need to control the time-out of that. If you happen do this to verify email addresses, there are other ways to do that.

Comment: Yes but with PHP we can detect if we run on Linux or Windows server, meaning that we can implement 2 binded solution in order to work on any server right ?